# Storing information as a single record

Tags: bash

I am trying to save all the data entered into the table as an individual record in the `contacts.txt` file like so

```
Record: 12
    Bob
     Roberts
     Bobs Stuff
     Bobby
     Bos Road
     Bobsville
     BB0 B22
     01234123456
```

At the moment my code is saving each field as an individual record like so

```
Record: 5
        Bob







==========================

Record: 6
       Roberts
```

and so on. How do I get round this?

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

BOOK="contacts.txt"

# set field names i.e. shell variables
forename=""
surname=""
company=""
position=""
street=""
town=""
postcode=""
phone=""


# open fd
exec 3>&1

# Store data to $VALUES variable
VALUES=$(dialog --ok-label "Submit" \
      --backtitle "Contacts" \
      --title "Add New Contact" \
      --form "Create a new contact" \
15 50 0 \
    "Forename:"   1 1   "$forename"     1 10 10 0 \
    "Surname:"    2 1   "$surname"      2 10 15 0 \
    "Company:"    3 1   "$company"      3 10 45 0 \
    "Position:"   4 1   "$position"     4 10 40 0 \
    "Street:"     5 1   "$street"       5 10 50 0 \
    "Town:"       6 1   "$town"         6 10 20 0 \
    "Postcode:"   7 1   "$postcode"     7 10 8 0 \
    "Phone:"      8 1   "$phone"        8 10 11 0 \
2>&1 1>&3)





# close fd
exec 3>&-

  # Echo the answers and ask for confirmation
        echo "Should I enter the values:"
        echo -e " $VALUES";
        echo -n "y/n: "
        read answer

        # Convert the answer to lower case
        fixedanswer=`echo $answer | tr "A-Z" "a-z"`;

        if [ "$fixedanswer" = "y" ] 
        then
            # Write the values to the address book
            echo "$VALUES" >>$BOOK
            echo "Added the entry OK"
            sleep 5
        else
            # Give the user a message
            echo -e " $VALUES \n NOT written to $BOOK"
            sleep 5
        fi

        exit 0
```

Comment: What's a "record" in a text file?

Comment: how I want it to save   ==========================

Record: 12
        Bob
         Roberts
         Bobs Stuff
         Bobby
         Bos Road
         Bobsville
         BB0 B22
         01234123456
==========================  ==========================

Record: 6
        w







==========================

Record: 7
        w







==========================

Record: 8
        w
How it is saving

Comment: @JamesCopland edit the question to include how you want the data to look - unreadable in a comment.

Comment: have done now @EtanReisner

Comment: Where is `Record:` in that script?

Comment: No the records are being stored in a text file called contacts.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

*echo "$VALUES" >>$BOOK*

remove the quotes around $VALUES.

Adding quotes will list each value as its own line of text. Removing the quotes considers it one line, printing each value with a space between them.